# How to sync a remote ASP site with local copy of the site?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I copied an entire ASP site from a remote server to my local machine. I can access the homepage, but once I try to login to the rest of the site, I receive the following error:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"

I set things up to allow for remote connections (enabling TCP/IP and Named Pipes), but is the problem because I'm trying to access a remote database? The connection string in Web.Config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ISBEPI_DEV" connectionString="Data Source=ERI-DB-06\DEVELOPMENT; 
  Database=ISBEPI_DEV; Initial Catalog=ISBEPI_DEV;Persist Security Info=True; 
  User ID=Pi_usr; Password =J6$h3Qoz#9Yw;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Please let me know if I can provide more info. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you specified incorrect connection string or you are not allowed to connect to that SQL server. Have you tried to connect to that database from SQL Management Studio or Server Explorer in Visual Studio?